# Android Studio TextView and sharedpreferences

Tags: android, textview

in one activity I save data into the sharedpreferences via:

```
public void createIt() {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    EditText editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);
    String s = editTextAge.getText().toString();
    age = Integer.valueOf(s);

    if (age < 16) {
        setWeightValues();
        setRepValues();

        switch (workoutPref) {
            case "fitness":
                //mat exercises
                editor.putString("sprints", "15" );
                editor.putString("jogs", "10");
                editor.putString("walks", "10" );
                break;
        }
   }

   editor.commit();
   launchNextactivity();
}
```

--

and in this new activity, I display 3 specific items from the memory and display them in a textview with this code inside onCreate()

```
public class WorkoutActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);

        //pagetabview 3 days 3 workouts

        TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        String t1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("Star Jumps", "nothing");
        txt1.setText(t1);

        TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        String t2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("Push Ups", "nothing");
        txt1.setText(t2);

        TextView txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        String t3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("Sit Ups", "nothing");
        txt1.setText(t3);

        TextView txt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        String t4 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("Plank", "nothing");
        txt1.setText(t4);

        TextView txt5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        String t5 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("Rowing", "nothing");
        txt1.setText(t5);

        TextView txt6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        String t6 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("Treadmill", "nothing");
        txt1.setText(t6);

    }
```

for some reason, it only puts "nothing" in the first textview, and then doesn't even change the other text views they stay as default. please can someone help, im not sure if its my sharedpreference or my way of setting textview

Comment: 1) you're not using the right keys. 2) you're using the same textview

Answer (score 0):

1. The key you have used for set and get values from shared preference should be the same.
2. You have not change textview value when finding textviews.

   ```
   TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
   TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
   TextView txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt3);
   TextView txt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt4);
   TextView txt5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt5);
   TextView txt6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt6);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

base from your code on putting data, this is how you get the data

getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("sprints", "nothing");